# How do i line plot a chart, with 57 rows, and 2820 colums of data?

Tags: excel

Excel seems not to enjoy the quantity of data i need to plot.

So i am considering, is it even possible with excel?

I have tried using pivot tables, but it splits the data into multiple parts, which i dont need.
I also tried Using a normal line plot, i get the error maximum 255 in a series.

Do i need to find alternative software for this plot?

Example of the data: [image]

Comment: You could unpivot your columns, if they're the same metrics, in power query so they move down the rows instead of the columns, then use a pivot table to plot from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time open question, in the mean time i found a answer which i will share.

I went outside Excel and found a old outdated app called DatPlot
and it worked like a charm..